# I can't set image from photo library to imageView, and got error Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 “query cancelled”

Tags: ios, swift, photolibrary

I'm developing an ios app using swift4.
When clicking profile image view, to set profile image on imageview, I have tap gesture call function.

The below is my code.
I implemented picker delegate using extension following swift guide.

Seeing several documents about the same problem, I think I did what I have to do. But I can't figure out error, and set image on imageview.
Please check my code.

```
import UIKit
import Kingfisher
import Alamofire
import Photos
class MyProfileVC: BaseNavigationVC {

@IBOutlet weak var stateMessageLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var profileImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var nicknameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var sexImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var hash1Button: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var hash2Button: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var hash3Button: UIButton!

let picker = UIImagePickerController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    picker.delegate = self

    picker.allowsEditing = true
    picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    picker.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary)!

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tappedProfileImageView))
    profileImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    profileImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true


}

@objc func tappedProfileImageView(){
    openGallery()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(false)
    self.checkPermission()


//I updated this part. this code works correctly
    if let imageUrl = UserInfo.shared().photoUri{
        let url = URL(string: imageUrl)

        profileImageView.layer.masksToBounds = false
        profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
        profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profileImageView.frame.size.width / 2
        profileImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        profileImageView.kf.setImage(with: url)

    }
}


func openGallery(){
    picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary

    present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)


}

func checkPermission() {
    let photoAuthorizationStatus = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
    switch photoAuthorizationStatus {
    case .authorized: print("Access is granted by user")
    case .notDetermined: PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({
        (newStatus) in
        print("status is \(newStatus)")
        if newStatus == PHAuthorizationStatus.authorized {
            print("success") }
    })
    case .restricted:
        print("User do not have access to photo album.")
    case .denied:
        print("User has denied the permission.")
    }
}
```

}

```
extension MyProfileVC : UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, 

UINavigationControllerDelegate{
    @objc func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage{


        self.profileImageView.image = image
        print(info)

    }

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

What would be cause of problem.

When I print info, debug area shows like this.

[__C.UIImagePickerControllerInfoKey(_rawValue: UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL): assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=54FE2CEF-59E7-4BCC-AF84-D64C1F32E58B&ext=JPG, __C.UIImagePickerControllerInfoKey(_rawValue: UIImagePickerControllerCropRect): NSRect: {{0, 0}, {2732.0000581881218, 2047.1787102689659}}, __C.UIImagePickerControllerInfoKey(_rawValue: UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage):  size {748, 560} orientation 0 scale 1.000000, __C.UIImagePickerControllerInfoKey(_rawValue: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType): public.image, __C.UIImagePickerControllerInfoKey(_rawValue: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage):  size {2732, 2048} orientation 0 scale 1.000000, __C.UIImagePickerControllerInfoKey(_rawValue: UIImagePickerControllerPHAsset):  54FE2CEF-59E7-4BCC-AF84-D64C1F32E58B/L0/001 mediaType=1/4, sourceType=1, (2732x2048), creationDate=2018-09-17 02:01:23 +0000, location=0, hidden=0, favorite=0 , __C.UIImagePickerControllerInfoKey(_rawValue: UIImagePickerControllerImageURL): file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/CD64C336-B5F1-48F6-9D54-504006ADD6E2/tmp/DD94F454-F3BE-4EF9-9F6F-0C90F61BEE19.jpeg]

Comment: Your code looks fine and it works on `Xcode 9.4.1`. That error looks like some `Xcode` glitch as it happens even when the image is retrieved successfully!

Comment: You need to put a breakPoint in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` and see what you are getting. Sometimes a slight change in method signature cause unexpected behavior.

Comment: @Kamran I added didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo result. Please check it out

Comment: As the image looks fine I think profileImageView might some issue. Can you try setting an image from your local assets to profileImageView on didFinishPickkngImage? This can help identifying the exact cause.

Comment: @Kamran Like you said, it is profileImageView. I added another imageView and set image using didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo. This new ImageView shows image normally. And I tried to set local image from assets on ProfileImageView. It didn't show image. However, in debug area, any errors didn't show up. In fact, I omitted some codes the above code, because I thought it is not related to the problem.  I added that omitted code in ViewWillAppear. Please see that.

Comment: @Kamran, When I re-execute without the code that I added in ViewWillappear. ProfileImageView shows image from photo library. Uhmmm. How can I solve this problem? I have to show profileImageView when starting this ViewController.

Comment: Ok, so `imagePicker` was not a problem. I am not sure if you are uploading this image to some server for later use. You can actually save this image in the app documents and then in `viewWillAppear`, check if the image exists in the documents then show that image.

Comment: @Kamran I solved it. It was viewWillAppear that confused me. After selecting photo from photo library, viewWillAppear still set previous image on imageView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my lack of programming thinking.
Though I selected a photo from photo library, after the Activity choosing photo closed, viewWillAppear set the previous image on ImageView.